# Find all homomorphisms of $(\mathbb{Z}, +, \cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to find all homomorphisms for ring $ (\mathbb{Z}, +, \cdot) $ ? Operations $+$ and $\cdot$ are usual operations of addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$. If you can, please provide a general approach to finding all homomorphisms in a ring.

It would also be great if you could do the same for groups. I also had another question for which I have the answer, to find all automorphisms of group $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$. However I do not understand it. I will write it out, it would be helpful if you could explain it since I really don't know the approach to these kind of problems.

Solution: Homomorphisms $f \colon \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ need to satisfy: $$ f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y)\\ f(x \cdot y) = f(x) \cdot f(y), \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$$
$$f(0+0) = f(0)+f(0) \implies f(0) = 0 \\$$ Let $$f(1)=a \in \mathbb{Q}$$ then $$f(2) = f(1+1) = f(1) + f(1) = 2a \\f(3) = f(1+1+1) =f(1+1)+f(1) =f(1)+f(1)+f(1)=3a \\ \dots \\f(n) =  n \cdot a $$ Next, $$f(n)+f(-n) = f(n+(-n)) = f(0) = 0\\ f(-n) = -f(n) = (-n)a$$
Similarly, for $\hspace{0,5cm}r= \frac{p}{q}, p \in \mathbb{Z}, q \in \mathbb{N}\hspace{0,5cm} f(r)= \frac{p}{q} \cdot a = ra. \hspace{1cm}$ So, $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q} \hspace{0,5cm} f(x)=xa.\\$ We got: $$f(x+y)=(x+y)a \\f(x)+f(y)=xa+ya = (x+y)a$$

Comment: Please [ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Comment: What does a "homomorphism of $\mathbb Z$" mean? In my understanding, homomorphisms are between *two* rings.

Comment: And why did we suddenly start talking about the rationals?

Comment: @KentaS Yes, between two rings $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. I am not a native English speaker and that's how we say it where I'm from.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The solution is for group $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ so I guess positive integers, negative integers and fractions had to be covered

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you, I will try

Comment: It seems you have [reposted this question verbatim after self-deleting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4447678/29335) which is a very bad thing to do.  This will be interpreted as you as trying to circumvent the moderation process and shed previous feedback you have been given.  The right thing to do is to listen to the feedback and use the edit button to improve your question.

Comment: When they go from a structure to itself, they are called "endomorphisms".

Comment: @rschwieb Yes I edited it and then decided to repost it since it got downvotes for it's unedited version, so I thought it wouldn't get read. I didn't know it was not allowed. Thank you. I am new here and still don't really know how this site functions. Should then I delete this question?

Comment: @Sara I'm inclined to let you take a mulligan this first time. As long as you are aware, it's ok to proceed with this one.

Comment: @Sara There are automatic systems which will impose bans on users once certain thresholds are met.  The details of these systems are kept secret (even from moderators), but it is an understood fact that posts with downvotes are detrimental, but *deleted* posts with downvotes are even worse.  If something you post is poorly received, *edit* it to improve it.  Deleting-and-reposting is likely to quickly trigger these automatic systems, which can prevent you from posting more questions.